# How to recover this crash issue when pdf loading by layer?app received EX_BAD_ACCESS signal

Tags: ipad

I have attached my code here.
Program get EX_BAD_ACCESS signal at this line:

```
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(self._document.page, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually results from a call to a deallocated object. Without seeing the exact error (which you really should include) or more code (specifically, where the referenced objects are created and retained/released), the best I can suggest is that you check that each of the objects you are referencing still exists at the time of reference.